# Parma Magica and telepathic communication

Tags: ars-magica-5, ars-magica, ars-magica-4

If we have an entity that uses magic to transmit certain of its thoughts in a telepathy-like manner to other beings through an effect that is equivalent to a Creo Mentem effect, can a magus with a parma magica - or another being with might - in excess of the level of effect of the first entity's magical level of effect perceive the communication being directed to them?

Is there any difference in the answer to this question between Ars 4 and Ars 5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless suppressed, a Parma Magica of sufficient level will prevent the creature from communicating with a Magus. The Mage will feel a pressure on their Parma, and will have to decide whether to suppress their Parma to allow the effect through. Without knowing that the pressure is from an attempt to communicate, most Magi would let their Parma block the effect rather than risk letting it through.

This is one of the reasons why the Order of Hermes doesn't use telepathic communication as a matter of course. How is a Mage to know if an incoming Creo Mentem effect is another Mage trying to invite them for lunch, or an enraged ghost attempting to seize control of their body?

The only difference between 5th edition and earlier editions would be how the magic resistance is resolved, the general principle would be the same.  <sub>Thanks [ironboundtome](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/10788).</sub>

Note that Parma Magica isn't the only form of magic resistance the telepath has to worry about. Any creature with Magic, Faerie, Demonic or Divine might has Magic Resistance which might block telepathic communication. If the telepathic communication is weak enough, even just the magic resistance from an individual being in an aura might be enough to block communication, for instance someone praying at the alter of a great Cathederal.

Comment: The only difference between 4e and 5e would be how the penetration rules resolve the resistance of MR. The overall problem and Mark Booth's answer is spot on.

Comment: You could have the ghost have a duplicate power or replacement power using Creo Imagonem, as CrIm base 1 will create a audio illusion (auditory species) and is not resisted. Just a thought.